# Put an event (click) on data tag

Tags: jquery

I had this code

```
<div id="toolbar" class="btn-group">
        <button class="btn btn-primary" type="button">Actions</button>
        <button class="btn btn-primary dropdown-toggle" type="button" data-toggle="dropdown" data-submenu="" aria-expanded="false">
            <span class="caret"></span>
        </button>

        <ul class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-right">
            <li><a id="cancelPaymentAction" tabindex="0">Annuler</a></li>
            <li><a id="savePaymentAction" tabindex="0">Sauvegarder</a></li>
            <li class="divider"></li>
            <li><a tabindex="0">Payer</a></li>
            <li class="pull-right"><a data-payment-mode="CASH" tabindex="0">Comptant</a></li>
            <li class="pull-right"><a data-payment-mode="ATM" tabindex="0">Débit</a></li>
            <li class="pull-right"><a data-payment-mode="CREDITCARD" tabindex="0">Carte de crédit</a></li>
            <li class="pull-right"><a data-payment-mode="GIFTCARD" tabindex="0">Carte cadeaux</a></li>
            <li class="pull-right"><a data-payment-mode="CHECK" tabindex="0">Chèque</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
```

I search a way to do a click on when we find a data-payment-mode tag.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe you are looking for the [has attribute selector](https://api.jquery.com/has-attribute-selector/) combined with the click event. In your case, this would look something like:

```
$('[data-payment-mode]').click(function() {
    var paymentMode = $(this).attr('data-payment-mode');
    alert( 'Payment mode '+paymentMode+' selected' );
});
```

[See this in action (JSFiddle)](https://jsfiddle.net/gxa9y0pq/)

Comment: nice,  although i'd indent the payment methods. Works though! :)